# Can't cash in Barry medal in Jetpack Joyride

Tags: ps3, jetpack-joyride

I've done all missions and got level 75 Barry medal, but I didn't cash in straight away. Now that I want to cash in, it won't let me. It's an option on the missions screen but I cannot select it. I've tried restarting the game and the console with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Pause your game and were it would normally show your missions it should have a cash in button, hit that.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work on consoles because this game was meant for mobile devices with touch screens and it will not select it with the controller.

Answer (score -1):

On the game over screen, tap the Missions tab. You have the option there.